# I am getting this error after running "Django manage.py migrate" command

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-migrations

This is all error I am getting:
PS E:\funds\Restaurant\restaurant> python manage.py makemigrations
Did you rename the menu.Order model to Orders? [y/N] n
Migrations for 'menu':
menu\migrations\0003_auto_20210417_2034.py
- Create model Orders
- Delete model Order

```
    PS E:\funds\Restaurant\restaurant> python manage.py migrate  
    Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, menu, sessions
    Running migrations:
      Applying menu.0003_auto_20210417_2034...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 394, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: table "menu_orders" already exists
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\funds\Restaurant\restaurant\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "E:\funds\Restaurant\restaurant\manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
        res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
        post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
        state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
        schema_editor.create_model(model)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in create_model
        self.execute(sql, params or None)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql)
      File "C:\Users\tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 394, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "menu_orders" already exists
```

## Generated by Django 3.0.11 on 2021-04-17 15:04

0003_auto_20210417_2034.py

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('menu', '0002_auto_20210409_1242'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Orders',
            fields=[
                ('order_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('items_json', models.CharField(max_length=5000)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=90)),
                ('email', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('address', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('state', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('zip_code', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(default='', max_length=111)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Order',
        ),
    ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class foodItems(models.Model):
    foodItems_id = models.AutoField
    foodItems_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='menu/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foodItems_name


class Contact(models.Model):
    msg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items_json = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=111, default="")

class OrderUpdate(models.Model):
    update_id  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField(default="")
    update_desc = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.update_desc[0:7] + "..."
```

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.11 on 2021-04-08 05:18

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Contact',
            fields=[
                ('msg_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('email', models.CharField(default='', max_length=70)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(default='', max_length=70)),
                ('desc', models.CharField(default='', max_length=500)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='foodItems',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('foodItems_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('category', models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)),
                ('subcategory', models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)),
                ('price', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('desc', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
                ('pub_date', models.DateField()),
                ('image', models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='menu/images')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Order',
            fields=[
                ('order_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('items_json', models.CharField(max_length=5000)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=90)),
                ('email', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('address', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('state', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('zip_code', models.CharField(max_length=111)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(default='', max_length=111)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='OrderUpdate',
            fields=[
                ('update_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('order_id', models.IntegerField(default='')),
                ('update_desc', models.CharField(max_length=5000)),
                ('timestamp', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please share your model before and after changes and your migrations file as well 0003_auto_20210417_2034.py

Comment: I have added files said by you

Comment: I think you messed up the migrations a bit. Can you check if you already have "migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Orders'," in any of the three migration files?

Comment: I have added now 1 more migration file: 0001_initial.py = Here migrations.CreateModel( name='Order') is written not "Orders". So what should I do now

Comment: Why do you have two models of order? Did you rename Orders model to Order or otherway?

Comment: thats what the error is :  Did you rename the menu.Order model to Orders? .. if you did not plan on renaming it to orders then please delete 003 file, rename model back to Order and run migrations